# Code Problem in my template.php

Tags: theming

Hello i have an awful feeling im just simply doing something fundamentally wrong. I think they are both the same function possin;y Can anyone tell me how to get it all together possibly? thanks

```
<?php


function ukf2_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 if (isset($vars['node'])) {
$vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type; //
}
}
// Finish copy Template for Content type


function ukf2_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first'])) {
    $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-10"';
  }

 else {
    $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-12"';
  }




if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['content_column_class2'] = ' class="col-sm-8"';
  }

 else {
    $variables['content_column_class2'] = ' class="col-sm-12"';
  }

}
```

Comment: sorry i get an error 500 when using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put all that logic into a single function:

```
function ukf2_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type; //
  }

  if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first'])) {
    $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-10"';
  }

  else {
    $variables['content_column_class'] = ' class="col-sm-12"';
  }

  if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['content_column_class2'] = ' class="col-sm-8"';
  }

  else {
    $variables['content_column_class2'] = ' class="col-sm-12"';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I have a feeling like this theme suggestion should be something like:

```
$vars['theme_hook_suggestion'][] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type;
```

And also you can make your code little short by something like this:

```
function ukf2_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'][] = 'page__'.$vars['node']->type; //
  }
  // Do your comment here.
  $variables['content_column_class'] = !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) ? ' class="col-sm-10"' : ' class="col-sm-12"';
  $variables['content_column_class2'] = !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second']) ? ' class="col-sm-8"' : ' class="col-sm-12"';
}
```

Comment: thanks very much Love. No errors but my column class2 has an erros. i must have some other problem to try track down. Ill try your code above too. Least now i can try things without the error. Again, thanks

Comment: no worries. Happens.!! Let me know if this works fine for you.

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for you.